# Visual Studio does not show names of loaded assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, assemblies

When running a c# project from inside Visual Studio, and watching the debug output, one can see when exactly each assembly is loaded.
(right-click debug output window, check "show module load messages")

From screenshots and other questions on StackOverflow I know that there should be a message for each assembly, containing the name of that assembly.
However on my pc *most of the time* all I get are nameless load messages. The name is missing.

I *can* see the names of all loaded modules when I go to the modules window (Debug menu, choose Windows, and then click Modules.)

How can I get the names to appear in the output window?
Under rare circumstances it appears to work, but I have been unable to reproduce these circumstances.

Here are the three types of assembly load messages I can see in the debug output window (sorry, German)

```
"MyProgram.vshost.exe" (Verwaltet): "Verwaltet" wurde geladen, das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"MyProgram.vshost.exe" (Verwaltet): "Verwaltet" geladen, Symbole geladen.
"MyProgram.vshost.exe" (Verwaltet): "Verwaltet" wurde geladen
```

Here is a rough translation into English

```
'MyProgram.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'Managed'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyProgram.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'Managed', loaded symbols.
'MyProgram.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'Managed'
```

Here is the output I would expect:

```
'Example.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\IdeaBlade.UI.WinForms.DevExpressControls.v2_2_0\3.6.7.1__287b5094865421c0\IdeaBlade.UI.WinForms.DevExpressControls.v2_2_0.dll'
'Example.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Example.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Example.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Example.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

The paths and names for the assemblies in the above log are what is missing on my pc.

(Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition)

Comment: `Ctrl+W,O` does this show the output as well as the output window

Comment: I can see the output window, and I can see the module load messages and the debug messages in there. But the module load messages have the module name missing. ctrl+w,o focuses that output window, but does not change the contents

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you please check if *'Modules Load Messages'* is enabled

   You could find it at:
   Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> General Output Settings-> Module Load Messages
2. Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)